# Can JMS Messaging be performed on quarkus using Apache camel routes?

Tags: quarkus

Sorry for a naive question , just starting off with quarkus here. Since i read that quarkus already supports camel , is it possible to create a JMS route to send a message to a JMS queue ?

I also have some legacy services which use Database bean map handlers (apache commons db). If i include them as a part of quarkus ,can these still be deployed on  GraalVM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of the component currently fully supported by camel-quarkus is listed here: https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/master/extensions

Other components not listed here are working out of the box in JVM mode but some work may be required ot make them working as native image